# What causes this program to return false even when the input number is present in the random given number?

Tags: java

I am writing a java program that asks the user to input a number between 0-9, generates a random number between 800 and 9999 and returns whether or not the user's input number is in the generated number. I am not sure why this isn't working, but it only seems to work if the inputted number is present more than once. For example: random number = 8445 input: 4 returns true. random number 8445 input: 5 returns false. I believe the problem lies in the for while loop/if statement of the containDigits method but after trial and error I can't seem to figure it out.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Lab12 {

public static void main(String[]args){
    Random rand = new Random();
    //(max - min +1 )+ min (creates range)
    int a = rand.nextInt(9999-800+1)+800;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter an integer between 0 and 9");
    int b = scanner.nextInt();

    if (b>9||b<0){
        System.out.println("Your number is invalid! Enter another one: ");
        b=scanner.nextInt();
    }

    boolean flag = containDigits(a,b);
    System.out.println(a+ " contains "+b+": "+flag);

}
public static boolean containDigits (int a, int b){
    boolean flag= false;
    while (a > 0){
        if (a % 10 == b){
            flag = true;
            a=a/10;
            break;

        }
        else {
            flag=false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return flag;

}
```

}

Comment: You always end your loop (using break) at the first iteration, since both the if block and the else block have a break. Execute your method, step by step, on paper. Or using your debugger. Add println() statements in the code to understand what happens if you don't want to learn how to use a debugger (which would be a huge mistake).

Comment: There's no need to divide by 10 in the "true" statement of the conditional. You don't need to search any more. Move it into the "false" statement.

Comment: Please rename your variables! `a` and `b` ? You may even find it easier to debug if they were say `number` and `digit`.

Comment: For 8445 as input and 4 as digit, your code answers ```false```, not ```true``` as you state. 5 returns ```true```, not ```false```.

Answer (score 0):

When you use break inside your loop (inside the if and else block) you're ending it in the first iteration.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know if i understand the `while` loop. If the last digit of a matches b, you have a match, flag gets true, you break the loop and return true. That seems fine to me. Why you divide a by 10 (without using a again) i cannot see. But if the LAST digit does NOT match, you set flag to false which it already is, and break the loop. You will never get to the 2nd last digit.

I would propose following changes:

- in the `if` branch, remove `a=a/10`;
- in the `else` branch, remove `flag = false`, add `a=a/10`, and replace `break` by `continue`.

```
public static boolean containDigits (int a, int b){
    boolean flag= false;
    while (a > 0){
        if (a % 10 == b){
            flag = true;
            break;

        }
        else {
            a = a/10;
            continue;
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
```

untested

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the usage of `break` in the `while` loop. You can check this post for more info. https://www.javatpoint.com/java-break

Answer (score 0):

Once you find a digit you no longer need to divide by 10 so you can just return true. If you do not find the digit you then do `a=a/10` and repeat the check with  `if (a % 10 == b)`. If the digit is not found we simply return false after the while loop.

```
public static boolean containDigits (int a, int b){

      while (a > 0){

         if (a % 10 == b) 
            return true;
         else 
            a = a/10;

      }
      return false;
   }
```